# Appending vector values to sublists

Tags: r, list, vector

Let's assume we have a list with three sublists: `list1 <- [[1,2],[4,5],[7,8]]`
and a vector: `vector1 <- c(3,6,9)`

Is there a way in R, without using loops, to append vector's values to the list, so we could get the result `list2 = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]` 
?
Thanks for all comments

Answer (score 3):

Use `Map`

```
Map(c, list1, vector1)

#[[1]]
#[1] 1 2 3

#[[2]]
#[1] 4 5 6

#[[3]]
#[1] 7 8 9
```

Or `lapply`

```
lapply(seq_along(list1), function(x) c(list1[[x]], vector1[[x]]))
```

---

The equivalent `purrr` variants can be

```
purrr::map2(list1, vector1, c)
purrr::map(seq_along(list1), ~c(list1[[.]], vector1[[.]]))
```

**data**

```
list1 <- list(c(1,2),c(4,5),c(7,8))
vector1 <- c(3,6,9)
```